# Why do I get "Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast com.motorola.intent.SYSTEM_DIALOG_POPUP"?

Tags: android, android-permissions, motorola

### Background

We have a very large and very popular app with quite a few permissions.

### The problem

It seems that on Motorola devices only (XT1254,XT1585,XT1565), with Android 5.1 and 5.1.1, we get crashes of this kind:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send 
broadcast com.motorola.intent.SYSTEM_DIALOG_POPUP from pid=15407, uid=10164
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2864)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1510)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:382)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:382)
       at android.app.Dialog$2.run(Dialog.java:316)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

The above statistics were collected using Crashlytics.

Not sure if it is because of this, but one of the app's permission is "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW", to be able to show content on top of other apps.

Thing is, this error seems to be because of Motorola's code itself, and I can't find anything about it over the Internet.

### What I've tried

Apart from searching the Internet about this exception, I've also tried to find how to contact Motorola itself, including finding a developer forum, but I've failed in doing so.

I've also tried posting about this on Android's group:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201631

### The question

What can be done in this case?

Why does it occur? Is it because of the permission? Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually me and my team mates faced the exact same problem when we were building an application which shows notes on top of other applications.

After researching for great lengths we found out that "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" permissions was made a signature permission and was causing problems by not letting the pop up appear from Lollipop 5.1

As a work around to it we need to explicitly ask the user to grant overlay permission for your app by doing this.

```
public void checkOverlayPermission(){
    if(!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:"+getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, ApplicationConstants.OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: wasn't it added on Android 6 and not 5.x ? Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION

Comment: Yes, every discussion I saw hinted that it was added on Marshmellow. But we tested it and after I granted the overlay permission it started working for 5.1 and 5.1.1 as well, this was working fine without the explicit permission in 5.0 though

Comment: How could this be? Did Motorola add this code before it was available for all?

Comment: I doubt it, one of the devices I tested on was nexus(5.1.1) and it din't work without the permissions

Comment: Here's a related discussion on it https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196597&q=label%3AComponent-Framework&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: This post was made by me, and I tested it on Android 6 and not 5.1.1 (even title says it) . Also, the exception never occurred on Nexus devices. Only on the devices I've mentioned. It also makes sense, because the exception has the name "motorola" in it . Are you absolutely sure that this is what you had? Please read the exception I wrote again.